# c# EventHandler inside a loop doesn't fire

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I am still a noob with events and I am having troubles updating a form using eventhandler.
I have a form which is a counter in the class StartPage, this counter should show  the value of the parameter "bookQuantity" which is calculated inside another class callsed Gauge. I subscribe to the eventHadler inside the while loop but it seems that the function Counter_Tick is never used, in debug the process pass over CounterEvent  and doesn`t start the Counter_Tick function.
Here it is the code (simplified):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zeus
{
    public class Gauge : IGauge
    {
        private IObjectsToPrint objectsToPrint = new ObjectsToPrint();
        private IOutputMessages outputMessages = new OutputMessages();
        private decimal bookQuantity;
        private float counter = Parameters.GetcounterToPrint;
        public EventArgs e = null;

        public delegate void CounterHandler(Gauge g, EventArgs e);

        private StartPage target;
        private EventHandler CounterEvent;

        public Gauge()
        {
            List<Books> ListToPrint = Parameters.GetList;
            bookQuantity = Parameters.FirstQuantity;
        }

        private long theCounter;

        public long TheCounter
        {
            get
            {
                return theCounter;
            }
            set
            {
                theCounter = value;
                OnCounterChanged(this.theCounter);
            }
        }

        public async void GaugeCalculator()
        {
            var ItemList = Parameters.GetList;
            bookQuantity = Parameters.FirstQuantity;
            Parameters._counterToPrint = (long)bookQuantity;
            // CounterEvent += new EventHandler(Counter_Tick);

            if (Parameters.Getgaugespeedvalue == 0)
            {
                //do nothing as we are not running
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var elem in ItemList)
                {
                    bookQuantity = Parameters.getQuantity(elem);

                    while (bookQuantity > 0)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000 / (Parameters.Getgaugespeedvalue + 1)));
                        CounterEvent += new EventHandler(Counter_Tick);
                        bookQuantity--;
                    }
                    if (bookQuantity == 0)
                        outputMessages.PrintFinished(Parameters.getTitle(elem));
                    // MessageBox.Show("hello");
                }
            }
        }

        public delegate void CounterTickerHandler(long newCount);

        public event CounterTickerHandler TheCounterChanged;

        public void Counter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TheCounter = (long)bookQuantity;
        }

        protected void OnCounterChanged(long newCount)
        {
            if (TheCounterChanged != null)
            {
                TheCounterChanged(newCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a different class (a Forms) I have:

```
namespace zeus
{
    public partial class StartPage : zeus.ParentForm
    {
        public StartPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.gauge = new Gauge();
            this.gauge.TheCounterChanged += new Gauge.CounterTickerHandler(CounterHasChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure. But in the code you posted, you haven't got any code that raises the `CounterEvent` event. Why would you expect any handlers to be called? The code has other problems, but I'd guess you're not bothering to actually raise the event, which would explain what you're seeing. FWIW: subscribing an event inside a loop without ever unsubscribing from the event is unlikely to have the effect you want; one hopes that was just a misguided attempt to track down the problem.

Comment: The code you have seems very far off-base. I recommend you ask a more general question, in which you describe the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve. I doubt the above is all that close to what a really good solution would look like. Granted, I can't say for sure, because it's not really clear from your question _what_ the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I did not see where the CounterEvent is ever raised.

Comment: You are right. It is a trivial error.